# How Do I Use the CSS attributes Min-width & Max-width?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have an HTML element, such as a table with a min and max width; I thought I would be able to use the following two attributes in CSS:

```
min-width
max-width
```

I want my table to have a minimum width of 1000px and a maximum width of 1230px; basically I want it to grow based on whats in the table elements TD. So,

```
min-width: 1000px;
max-width: 1230px;
```

Will this work? It doesn't seem to work for me as I want so I know I don't understand something; basically my table is always 1000px and it won't grow even if I try and force the size of a TD by giving it a large width. Table basically starts like this,

```
<table style="min-width: 1000px;max-width: 1230px;">...
```

Comment: It would help if you created a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the issue

Comment: As well as a reference to your browser version.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe http://jsbin.com/bovuvele/3/edit / http://jsbin.com/bovuvele/2/edit / http://jsbin.com/bovuvele/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the JS Bin examples; this shows that the below references are incorrect (regarding these attributes not being supported in table) and suggests there is some syntax error in the actual code I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `width:100%` so the table *tries* to grow to fit its container, but is constrained by its `max-width`.

Comment: That isn't true. The default width is `auto`, which (for a `display: table`) element will be as small as possible while fitting the content and obeying the min-width. As you can see, [min-width works fine without specifying a width](http://jsbin.com/bovuvele/1/).

Comment: @Quentin Which part isn't true? `min-width` isn't in question, we're talking about `max-width` if you read the question. The table is sitting fixed at `1000px`, which is the `min-width`. He's asking how to make it expand to hit the `max-width`. I'm telling him that he needs to add `width:100%` to achieve that goal.

Comment: He's trying to make it expand by having a large `td` (not to the max width, if he wanted it at the max width he could just use width instead of max width in the first place), and it does: http://jsbin.com/bovuvele/2/

Comment: @Quentin He wants a table that expands, but is constrained to between 1000 to 1230 pixels. He can't use `width: 1230px` to achieve that; that would produce a table that was always 1230px wide, even if the window was smaller than that.

Comment: @Quentin As my answer indicates, I fixed your JSBin simply by adding `width: 100%`: http://jsbin.com/bovuvele/4/.

Comment: The question says "basically I want it to grow based on whats in the table elements TD" not "to fill the window"